# How to create manual scripts for button click using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I tried to write manual scripts in JMETER.
How the parameters to pass for button click from HTTP Request?

While I inspect the button, I am getting.. class, button name.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please read the following post before posting a question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Give some examples on what you have tried so far, and any errors you may of encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you click [HTML Button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) it should trigger submission of [HTML Form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) so inspect the associated form to see the relevant URL, method and parameters.

However I believe that recording your test using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is much faster and easier way of generating necessary [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

You can also consider an alternative way of recording JMeter tests which is capable of exporting recorded scenarios in "SmartJMX" mode performing automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters so you will be even just record and replay without taking extra steps manually, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for details.